# How can I redirect an entire domain to a subfolder except for / and /index.html?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an entire domain to a subfolder of that domain except for / and /index.html.

So all pages and folders within domain.com should redirect to domain.com/folder/ except for domain.com and domain.com/index.html.

This is what I'm using but it's not working properly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /folder [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule !^folder/|(index\.html)$ folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

- Always have redirect before internal rewrite to avoid exposing your internal URIs to external clients and browsers
- Negative condition `!^folder/|(index\.html)?$` will rewrite every URI except the `/`, `/index.html` and anything that starts with `/folder/`
- Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache or test in a new browser instance